# Misleading text when answers are added and edited on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

I was browsing a question using the app, and then I got a green bar at the top that said:

> **3 new and edited answers.** Tap to reload.

[image: image of bug]

Only one new answer was added, and 2 were edited, so something like "3 new or edited answers" might work.

I know the app isn't under development right now, but can this misleading text be fixed if it's ever developed again?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 4S
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)